# How to handle the Second Click on a CardView

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener, android-cardview

Okay, I'm just trying to handle the second click on a `CardView`.

For example, Now when i(or a user) clicks on the `CardView`, It will make the `CardView`, `TRANSPARENT` and also, `Focusable` and some other stuffs like adding `Android` text into a `EditText`.

So, I need to handle when user or i myself clicked on the `CardView` **for the second time**, `CardView` changes to `Color.WHITE` and set `Focusable` to `false` or other stuffs...

How can i do that?

**Here is what i did so far:**

```
 final CardView cvAnd = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.and_cv);
        cvAnd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                cvAnd.setTag("FirstClick");
                if (cvAnd.getTag().equals("FirstClick") && TextUtils.isEmpty(mTagField.getText().toString())) {
                    mTagField.setText(R.string.android);
                } else {
                    mTagField.setText(mTagField.getText() + "Android");
                }
                cvAnd.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                cvAnd.setFocusable(true);

                //First click

                cvAnd.setTag("SecondClick");
                if (cvAnd.getTag().equals("SecondClick")) {
                    cvAnd.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    cvAnd.setFocusable(false);

                }

                //Second click maybe?
            }
        });
```

The idea was to set the tag(***in the first time click***) to `FirstClick` then handle it if tag was the `FirstClick` doing the first click stuffs and so on...

But, The thing is, I don't really have clue about How to handle that **second time click**.

Comment: Why not using a simple global boolean? (it's the easiest solution if you need to handle only 1 card at time)

Comment: Well, Let's say there are few Cards that user wants to select like that..It can be 1 to 10 or etc..Anyways, Can you make your idea as an answer? Because whatever i think, It does not match with my expectation you know...That would be great

Comment: More cards = Adapter. If you are using a RecyclerView you can save a boolean inside the ViewHolder and use it to handle the logic. Then when the ViewHolder is reused you can reset the state to the default value.

Comment: I don't want to use `Adapter` yet, let's focus on one `CardView`, And Here is my try with boolean : https://paste.ofcode.org/xpKsEDMDa7bNQvL2eTmLQ4 Please let me know what was your idea as an answer...

Comment: i've posted a solution with Adapter and RecyclerView, i will see your approach ASAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a proof of concept as you asked. Let me know if you don't understand something.

```
public class CardViewAdapter extends extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public boolean isFirstSelected;
        public CardView cardView;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card);
        }

        public void reset(){
            //put here all the properties which need to be resetted
            isFirstSelected = false;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_row, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //set card click listener here and use
        //holder.isFirstSelected to handle the internal logic
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(MyViewHolder holder) {
        //reset the viewholder state
        holder.reset();
    }

}
```

I've took your snippet and tried to translate the logic into this. Probably you need to change the logic but now you have a starting point.

```
final CardView cvAnd = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.and_cv);
    cvAnd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!isClicked) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mTagField.getText().toString())) {
                    mTagField.setText(R.string.android);
                    cvAnd.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    cvAnd.setFocusable(true);
                }

            } else {
                if (mTagField.getText().toString().contains("Android")) {
                    mTagField.getText().clear();
                } else {
                    mTagField.setText(mTagField.getText() + ", Android");
                }
                cvAnd.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                cvAnd.setFocusable(false);
            }
            //reverse boolean
            isClicked = !isClicked;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot :) What a sweet approach :)

Comment: Thank you, `Probably you need to change the logic but now you have a starting point.`  Indeed, Because it adds the text twice in the second click, I'll handle that too. This was the main issue which you solved it, Thanks again.

Comment: I've edited your answer and added the working code If you don't mind,  which it took a while to figuring out. But who cares, Let's be helpful for the future searches :)

Comment: i've optimized your edit a bit merging duplicated code ;)

Comment: Actually, This was the final output of what i did in conjection with yours: https://paste.ofcode.org/38GYCrJrGj9U4Kfu3esPHyN And this one works better..Thanks again :)